# Concatenated string results in ORA-00911: Invalid Character error

Tags: oracle11g, vb6

I am running a query using vb6.0.
The database is Oracle 11g.

The code goes like this:

```
dim strSearch as string
dim sqlSearch as string
dim rsSearch as new adodb.recordset
dim Connect2Oracle as new Adodb.connection

Connect2Oracle.ConnectionString="provider=MSDAORA.1;User ID=xxxxxx........
connect2Oracle.open

strSearch="('B&M','WC&S','DC-9')"

sqlSearch="Select SL_NO from Party where Code in " & strSearch & ";""

rs.open sqlSearch, Connect2Oracle, adOpenForwardOnly, adLockReadOnly, adCmdText
```

I get an *ORA-00911: Invalid Character* error.

The query runs on Toad if I replace the Ampersand with `|| chr(38) ||` but with VB6.0 I get an error.

```
strSearch=('B'|| chr(38) || 'M','WC' || chr(38) || 'S','DC-9')
```

I know it has something to do with the single quotes, when I am replacing the Ampersand with `|| chr(38) ||`.

I just cannot seem to figure out how to resolve this issue.

Any support, suggestions and advice highly appreciated.

Dandy

Comment: Should `strSearch` be in double quotes - i.e. `strSearch="('B&M','WC&S','DC-9')"` ? And is the trailing `& "` really supposed to be there? It's unclear why you're building the query like this, but if the plan is to use variables instead of fixed values then you should like at bind variables and collections instead of risking SQL injection. (The ampersand is unlikely to be a problem; some clients use it to mark substitution variables, I doubt that applies here.)

Comment: @AlexPoole
I am building the strSearch through code.
Also, the & in the string list is from the table.
Since strSearch is declared as a string the double quotes is not required.
But the & creates an issue as Oracle treats it as a variable, that needs to be input by the user.
Unfortunately, ADODB cannot interpret the error well and returns an ORA-00911: Invalid character error.
Funny part is if I copy the query from my code and run it in Toad (after the strSearch is populated through code), it executes without any error and returns desired rows and values.

Comment: @AlexPoole. I had posted a question some time back on building a similar search string during run-time...here https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/76857063/2

Comment: This may not solve the issue, but the last code snippet likely needs to be more like this: `strSearch = "('B'||" & Chr(38) & "|| 'M','WC' ||" & Chr(38) & "|| 'S','DC-9')"`.

Comment: @BrianMStafford. & Chr(38) & won't work. But if I omit the & before and after the chr(38), it works in Toad. For some reason I am getting ORA-00911:Invalid Character error.

Comment: Is this your real code? Because if the RHS of `strSearch=` is not in double quotes I don't even think it would compile. There's no point in debugging something that might be copy & pasted wrong.

Comment: @StayOnTarget. This code is just part of the project.

Comment: [Resolved].......The culprit was the Semi Colon at the end of the query. While Toad accepts it, ADODB doesn't seem to like the semi colon at the end of the query. 

My thanks to each one of you, who contributed and put in efforts to help me.